# React Native: Implementing Grid with Touch Selection

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native application where I'm trying to select a word by dragging finger on a grid of characters. It is similir to word search game. But when I drag my finger, only first cell of the grid is selected. [word search game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stIhD.jpg)

when I drag, row and col value doesn't change.

Here is the code that I have tried:

`your text`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

type PropType = {
  grid: string[][];
  words: string[];
};
const gridSize = 4;

const GridOfCells: React.FC<PropType> = ({ grid, words }) => {
  const [selectedWord, setSelectedWord] = useState<string>("");
  const [selectedCells, setSelectedCells] = useState<number[][]>([]);
  const [panActive, setPanActive] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const data: string[] = grid.flat();

  const handleCellSelection = (row: number, col: number) => {
    // console.log({ row, col });

    // Ensure the cell is not already selected
    if (!selectedCells.find((cell) => cell[0] === row && cell[1] === col)) {
      setSelectedCells([...selectedCells, [row, col]]);
      setSelectedWord(selectedWord + grid[row][col]);
    }
  };

  const isCellSelected = (row: number, col: number) => {
    return selectedCells.some((cell) => cell[0] === row && cell[1] === col);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    for (const word of words) {
      if (selectedWord === word) {
        // Handle a found word
        setSelectedWord("");
        setSelectedCells([]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }, [selectedWord, words]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{selectedWord}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <PanGestureHandler
            onGestureEvent={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              if (nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
                setPanActive(true);
                const row = Math.floor(index / gridSize);
                const col = index % gridSize;

                console.log({ row, col });

                // If this is a new selection, clear previous selections
                if (!panActive) {
                  setSelectedCells([]);
                  setSelectedWord("");
                }

                if (!isCellSelected(row, col)) {
                  handleCellSelection(row, col);
                }
              }
            }}
            onHandlerStateChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              if (nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
                setPanActive(false);
              }
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={[
                styles.cell,
                isCellSelected(
                  Math.floor(index / gridSize),
                  index % gridSize
                ) && (panActive ? styles.selectedCell : {}),
              ]}
            >
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          </PanGestureHandler>
        )}
        numColumns={gridSize}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item}-${index}`}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cell: {
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  selectedCell: {
    backgroundColor: "darkgray",
  },
});

export default GridOfCells;
```